# Sum of fractional parts over coprime residues

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $q$ be a positive integer and $\theta$ a real number with $0 \leq \theta < 1$. Consider the two sums
$$
S_\theta^\pm(q)=\sum_{\substack{r=1\\ (r,q)=1}}^{q-1} \left\{\theta\pm\frac{r}{q} \right\},
$$
where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part. Intuitively, the fractions $r/q$ should equidistribute in the interval $[0,1]$, and so replacing the fractional part by its expected value of $\frac{1}{2}$, we expect
$$
\tag{1}
S_\theta^\pm(q)=\frac{\varphi(q)}{2} + E,
$$
where is $E$ is some small error term. This certainly seems like the sort of thing someone has computed at some point, but I am at a loss as to how to track it down. I'm sure I could prove this myself, but I'd rather not take the time if someone has already done it. Thus my question:

**Does anyone know of a reference for the equation (1)?**

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: We have $S^+_\theta(q) = \sum_{d \mid q} \mu(q/d) \sum_{r=0}^{d-1} \left \{ \theta + \frac{r}{d} \right\} =  \sum_{d \mid q} \mu(q/d) ( \frac{d-1}{2}  + \{ d \theta\} )  = \frac{\varphi(q)}{2}  + \sum_{d \mid q} \mu(q/d)  \{ d \theta\}  = \frac{\varphi(q)}{2}  +E$ with $E \leq 2^{ \omega(q)}$ with $\mu$ the Möbius function and $\omega$ the number of prime factors.